# python requests post with redirect fails

Tags: python, forms, post, python-requests

I'm trying to get some train ticket times and prices from : https://www.voyages-sncf.com/billet-train using requests.
So far, I cannot seem to get anywhere.

```
    url = 'https://www.voyages-sncf.com/billet-train' 
    formData = {
            'ORIGIN_CITY': 'PARIS',
            'DESTINATION_CITY': 'BORDEAUX',
            'OUTWARD_DATE': '30/09/2017',
            'TRAVEL_TYPE': 'AS',
            'OUTWARD_SCHEDULE_TYPE': 'DEPARTURE_FROM',
            'OUTWARD_TIME': '07h'
            }
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=formData, proxies = proxyDict)
print(r)
print(r.headers)
```

First I don't get why I get a 200 http code...
Also, the only thing I manage to land on is an error page (following Request.history)

```
print(r.history)
print(r.history[0].headers["Location"])
print(r.history[1].headers["Location"])
print(r.history[2].headers["Location"])
print(r.history[3].headers["Location"])
```

Doing the same thing by hand and watching what goes on I can see that filling the form redirects me to :

https://www.voyages-sncf.com/recherche-en-cours?hid=2BH,

then to voyages-sncf.com/vsc/proposals/findProposals?hid=2BH,

then finally to voyages-sncf.com/proposition?clientId=4765cf49-d109-4a93-83ff-3c21182d7891&language=fr&country=FR, where the prices and times are.

I tought that requests could handle redirects but I must be missing something...
Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Same issue here, although on a different website. Couldn't find any documentation on how to handle this!